# How to get parent value

Tags: jquery, parent

I have this basic code in my html document:

```
<div class="database_name" style="background: rgb(243, 243, 243);">
    <i class="minus_sign fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
    <div id="hovering_div_inside">
        <i class="fa fa-database database_sign"></i>
        <span class="dat_name">Example</span>
    </div>
    <div class="appended">
        <div class="create_new_table">
            <i class="fa  fa-pencil">
                <span class="create_new_table_span">New</span>
            </i>
        </div>
        <span class="table_names_from_database"></span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I need to get the word example `$(".dat_name).text()` when ever I click on `$(".create_new_table_span")` on New.

It should be dynamic not only one time and also there are many `NEW` links selector `parent()` does not work.

Comment: Great!!! Appreciated!!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the closest `.database_name` and then `.dat_name` under it on click of `.create_new_table_span` like following.

```
$('.create_new_table_span').click(function(){
   var text =  $(this).closest('.database_name').find('.dat_name').text();
   alert(text);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".create_new_table_span").click(getDataName);

function getDataName(e){
  var name = $(e.target).closest('.database_name').find('.dat_name').text();
  //do what ever you want with the name.
}
```

Using the [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) Method you will get the first nearest element, matching the selector. And [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) searches the children tree of an element.

You can also use find() directly on the click target:

```
$(e.target).find('.dat_name');
```